# C++ OpenCL: what happens to a subbuffer when a buffer goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, opencl

I haven't been able to find a clear source on how memory deallocation is handled by OpenCL's C++ wrapper; any pointer to such a reference would be great.

My particular question right now is, what happens if a buffer goes out of scope before a corresponding subbuffer? Say, in this scenario:

```cpp
cl::Buffer *buf=new cl::Buffer;
*buf=cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 1000);
cl_buffer_region reg={20, 50};
cl::Buffer sub=buf->createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &reg);
delete buf;
```

Does the device memory allocated get deallocated, leaving buf pointing to an invalid memory address, or does the program wait for sub to also be destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ wrappers for OpenCL use reference counting, provided by the native OpenCL API (see [`clRetainMemObject`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clRetainMemObject.html) and [`clReleaseMemObject`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clReleaseMemObject.html) for reference) to keep track of each buffer. It might be accurate to think of them as being implemented something like this:

```
class cl::Buffer {
    cl_mem buffer;
public:
    Buffer(/*...*/) { buffer = clCreateBuffer(/*...*/);} //Implicit Retain
    Buffer(Buffer const& o) {buffer = o.buffer; clRetainMemObject(buffer);}
    ~Buffer() {clReleaseMemObject(buffer);}

    /*...*/
};
```

This also holds true for subbuffers: they use the same internal reference counting mechanism as the main buffer (`clCreateSubBuffer` is stated to [implicitly call retain on the object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clRetainMemObject.html) producing the buffer), so it'll be reference-counted as well, and remain valid so long as the owning object remains, holding onto a reference to the original buffer object as well.

This code might help:

```
cl::Buffer do_stuff() {
    cl::Buffer buffer{context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 1000};
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << buffer.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //Should print "Ref Count: 1" to console

    cl::Buffer copy = buffer; //retain
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << buffer.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //Should print "Ref Count: 2"
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << copy.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //Should print "Ref Count: 2"

    cl_buffer_region reg={20, 50};
    cl::Buffer sub = buffer.createSubBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION, &reg); //retain
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << buffer.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //Should print "Ref Count: 3"
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << sub.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //I believe it prints "Ref Count: 1", but if it inherits the main buffer's reference count,
    //then it'll print "Ref Count: 3" instead. Not sure what the actual specification is

    return sub;
    //release buffer
    //release copy
}

void outer_code() {
    cl::Buffer subBuffer = do_stuff();
    //Should print "Ref Count: 1", "Ref Count: 2", "Ref Count: 2", "Ref Count: 3", "Ref Count: 1", in order
    std::cout << "Ref Count: " << subBuffer.getInfo<CL_MEM_REFERENCE_COUNT>() << std::endl;
    //Should print "Ref Count: 1"

    //End of scope: release subBuffer
}
```

We can also confirm that, using the retain/release semantics, the original buffer will not be deleted until the subbuffers are also deleted because the specification says so:

> After the `memobj` reference count becomes zero and commands queued for execution on a
>   command-queue(s) that use `memobj` have finished, the memory object is deleted. **If `memobj` is a buffer object, `memobj` cannot be deleted until all sub-buffer objects associated with memobj are deleted.** Using this function to release a reference that was not obtained by creating the object or by calling `clRetainMemObject` causes undefined behavior
>
> —**clReleaseMemObject**, OpenCL 2.0 Specification, [pg. 156](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf#page=156)

So under the assumption that the C++ OpenCL Wrapper is implemented correctly, then it is safe to say that the subbuffer will persist after you've deleted the owner for the original buffer object, because the original will be deleted using the retain/release semantics, and thus maintained until the subbuffer is deleted.